# How to include javascript file in the cs code behind in asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

In default.aspx I have:

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:Button ID="clikme" runat="server" Text="click me" />    
    </div>
    </form>
```

In default.aspx I have:

```
clikme.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "javaScript: return myfunction();");
```

And in JScript1.js I have

```
function myFunction() {
    alert('this is my function');
    return false;
}
```

The above code does not work it shows 'Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object expected'. I can't figure out how to find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are call function with wrong name myfunction() should be myFunction() as javascript is case sensitive. Also make sure you include the `JScript1.js` in the current aspx file. You can read this [MSDN artile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3hc29e2a%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#IncludingCustomClientScriptinASP.NETPages) to learn how to include js file.

```
clikme.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "javaScript: return myFunction();");
```

To include js file

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="yourDirectorIfAny/JScript1.js" ></script>
```

Comment: How you include js file, just put some alter in js file to ensure your js file is being included.

Answer (score 0):

try this 
add

script type='text/javascript' language="javascript" to your js portion and place your function inside it..

Answer (score 0):

try

```
clikme.Attributes.Add("OnClientClick", "javaScript: return myFunction();");
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to give reference of javascript file on Aspx page itself as suggested by Adil. If you want to register some javascript methods in code behind then you can have a look at this example.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.registerclientscriptblock.aspx

Answer (score 0):

JScript is CASE SENSITIVE language.

```
clikme.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "javaScript: return myfunction();");
function myFunction() {
...
}
```

Check above lines. myFunction function must be equal.

Answer (score 0):

```
Something like below will helpfull.. 

string script = "myFunction();";
AjaxControlToolkit.ToolkitScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alert", script, true);
```